# counting number of specific string in each row

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a SNP table looks like this

```
A N N N N N N N N N N N
N C N N N C N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N N
N C N N N C N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N N
C C N N N N N N N N N N
C C N N N C C N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N N
```

I want to count total number of N in each row? any idea how to do that

Comment: What is your desired output?  Which column is a genotype? I don't see anything in `pop.file` that matches anything in `genotypes.file`.

Comment: it's unclear how those 2 files relate to each other

Comment: @Jesse_b       . columns 3-317 in the genotypes file are individuals with the same other as in pop.file.... I want to pull individuals from each population together and count the number of N genotypes fro the entire population.

Comment: You say the third column in the genotypes file should be `HT185_MK8-2`, but all I see is the letter `N` over and over.

Comment: the third column is entirely belong to HT185_MK8-2 individual, N meaning missing genotype at that particular SNP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`.

```
awk -F\N '{print NF-1}' infile
```

Or.

```
awk -F\N '$0=NF-1' infile
```

Or.

```
awk '{print gsub(/\<N\>/, "")}' infile
```

Or to identifying in which line:

```
awk -F\N '$0="line "NR": "NF-1' infile
```

Comment: Thanks. And this works as well! awk 'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/N/,"") "\t" NR}' file.name

Comment: You are welcome! "Yes". but it will count `NN` two times, you can use `\<...\>` to tell `gsub` it's a word boundary

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count the occurrences of a specific character `N` in each line, then

```
perl -lne 'print tr/N//' infile
```

If you want to be stricter, and count the number of whitespace delimited columns consisting exactly of the string `N`, then

```
perl -alne 'print scalar grep { $_ eq "N" } @F' infile
```